# Pandas: using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
ID    domain    category    active_seconds
111   vk.com    Social_network   42
111   facebook.com   Social_network   18
222   vk.com      Social_network     50
222   gmail.com   E-mail    50
```

If I use

`df.groupby(['category', 'domain']).agg({'ID': pd.Series.nunique, 'active_seconds': np.sum}).rename(columns={'ID': 'all_users', 'active_seconds': 'all_time'}.reset_index()`

I get with it

`category          domain   all_users    all_time
 Social_network    vk.com      2            92
 Social_network    facebook.com    1        18
 E-mail            gmail.com       1        50`

But is any way to get report in this format:

```
category          domain     all_users     all_time
Social_network                   2            110
                   vk.com        2             92
                  facebook.com   1             18

E-mail                           1             50
                   gmail.com     1             50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new `DataFrame` by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) `sum` and [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and add new level of [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html), last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
#omit reset_index
df1 = df.groupby(['category', 'domain'])
        .agg({'ID': pd.Series.nunique, 'active_seconds': np.sum})
        .rename(columns={'ID': 'all_users', 'active_seconds': 'all_time'})

df2 = df1.groupby('category').agg({'all_users': 'nunique', 'all_time': 'sum'})

df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.index, [''] * len(df2.index)],
                                       names=('category','domain'))
print (df2)
                       all_time  all_users
category       domain                     
E-mail                       50          1
Social_network              110          2

print (pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index())
                             all_time  all_users
category       domain                           
E-mail                             50          1
               gmail.com           50          1
Social_network                    110          2
               facebook.com        18          1
               vk.com              92          2
```

Another solution for new `DataFrame` is create new column by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df2 = df1.groupby('category').agg({'all_users': 'nunique', 'all_time': 'sum'})
         .assign(domain='')
         .set_index('domain', append=True)
print (df2)
                       all_time  all_users
category       domain                     
E-mail                       50          1
Social_network              110          2
```

Comment: Can you say, how can I print number of unique users to category, not sum?

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you advise me some books or anything else to improve skills?

Comment: It returns me an error `KeyError: 'url_Maincategory'` in`df2 = df1.groupby('category').agg({'all_users': 'nunique', 'all_time': 'sum'})`

Comment: What is `print (df1.columns.tolist())`?  Keyerror means obviously you want select some column which not exist. But here it is interesting, because uses only columns `all_users`, `all_time` and `category`. Maybe problem is `'url_Maincategory` column is lost and you need it later in code. Can you check it?

Comment: Sorry, I mean `KeyError: 'category`. I have another name of columns and in my data `category` called `url_Maincategory`. And I have columns `['all_users', 'all_time']`. But if I add to `df1` `reset_index()`, I have `['url_Maincategory', 'domain', 'all_users', 'all_time']`. But then I get error `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'` in `df = (pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index())`

Comment: It seems there is problem in indexes, there are some tuples. Maybe help `df1.index = df.index.astype(int)`. Also is possible check `print (df.index)` and check if something wrong or not common.

Comment: I have a problem again. After `df1.index = df.index.astype(int)` I get error `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6506 elements, new values have 968034 elements` and `df.index` returns `Int64Index([     0,      1,      2,      3,      4,      5,      6,      7,
            968050, 968051, 968052, 968053, 968054, 968055, 968056, 968057, 968058, 968059],
           dtype='int64', length=968034)`

Comment: You need same index convert to int `df1.index = df1.index.astype(int)` not `df1.index = df.index.astype(int)`, change df.index to df1.index

Comment: and error again `TypeError: Setting <class 'pandas.indexes.multi.MultiIndex'> dtype to anything other than object is not supported`

Comment: Hmm, do you create new level of Multindex by `df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.index, [''] * len(df2.index)]` and still problem? You need Mulriindex in both DataFrames for align. Or problem is silution works with sample and with real data not?

Comment: If I use `df1 = df.groupby(['url_Maincategory', 'domain']).\
            agg({'ID': pd.Series.nunique, 'active_seconds_2': np.sum}).\
            rename(columns={'ID': 'all_users', 'active_seconds_2': 'all_time'}).reset_index()
        df1.index = df1.index.astype(int)
        df2 = df1.groupby('url_Maincategory').agg({'all_users': 'nunique', 'all_time': 'sum'})
        df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.index, [''] * len(df2.index)])
        df = (pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index())` I get `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`

Comment: And problem is only with real data or also with sample? If data not confidental, is posssible send csv to my email? Thanks.

Comment: I've sent you email to `jozefeg@gmail.com`

Comment: Thank you, but I dont get it yet.

Comment: Sorry, I get it.

Comment: I find problem, see email.